# ESO - What is this skill

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In the following clip

I don't recognize the icon for the 5th skill on bar. Can anyone tell me what it is (you can see the icon during whole clip, but check min 1:11 for a clear view)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the **Silver Leash** upgrade from **Silver Bolts**. A skill locatet in the **Fightersguild** tree.

You can have a look at the icon to compare and it's function [here](http://eso-skills.com/skill?z=L4OWGRau@Cxrw0uu%25Cxrw0uu@Cxrw0uu), If you want to check out the stats just go [here](http://eso-skills.com/skill/) and select Guild -> Fighters Guild -> and the dots next to Silverbolts.

Answer (score 1):

It's **Silver Shards** from the **Fighers Guild** skill line. Keep in mind that (I think) it's one of the several abilities that got reworked in the recent *Dark Brotherhood* DLC release.

Comment: +1 Both added answers are what I need. I'm gonna accept Shaeldon because he has lower rep (although yours was first), I'm sorry but I can't accept 2 :).

Comment: @zozo no worries, his is more elaborate anyway